# Numerical integration of a function of an empirical CDF

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I have the following equation $y = f(x)$ and I want to invert $f(\cdot)$ to find $x$ numerically. Because the function $f(\cdot)$ is quite complex I will solve $y - f(x) = 0$ instead, using the `uniroot` function in `R`. My problem is that $f(x)$ contains an integral, which depends on the distribution of $X$, say $X \sim G(\cdot)$, with $X \in [\underline{x}, \overline{x}]$. I observe realizations $x$ of $X$ and $\hat{G}(x)$ is defined as the empirical distribution of $X$ at $x$.

The integral I need to solve numerically is $\int_x^{\overline{x}} s [1-G(s)]^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}} dG(s)$. Assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known parameters in [0,1] for the time being (e.g. $\alpha =.2, \beta = .3$). How to integrate the function?

Comment: Are there reasons for not using numerical integration?

Comment: Actually, I would like to integrate numerically, but I do not know how. One of the problems I have is that the object of interest is at the lower boundary of the integral.